# get formData from array of Fields

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm stuck. I've got this `getFormData` function and I'm wondering if it possible to have the result object of it to be typed?
Like I wanted to know that based on the `fields` input there will be `name` and `isChecked` keys and they will have string and boolean values. I'm not sure if it is even possible. Please let me know what do you think? cheers!

```
interface Input { 
    type: 'text';
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

interface Checkbox { 
    type: 'checkbox';
    name: string;
    value: boolean;
}

type Field = Input | Checkbox;

const fields: Field[] = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'text',
        value: 'my name',
    },
    {
        name: 'isChecked',
        type: 'checkbox',
        value: false,
    }
];

const getFormData = (fields: Field[]) => fields.reduce((all, current) => ({
  ...all,
  [current.name]: current.value
}), {});


const { name, isChecked } = getFormData(fields);
```

It shouts on properties `name` and `isChecked` does not exist on type '{}' right now.
There is a link to [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN7IBQyJyYAnhhAFzIDkkAHmHQNzGkhwC2NyAzmCigA5u1LIAbnAA2WPoOEgxhAL6FCoSLEQoAwgAsICANYAjAPaN8RCRSq06CI6cuM2HEl161Fo8aTScnyWFjIQcCDs6oT2KABiwBAyACbIALxomDjIAD7IhsbmVuyECBYggsgwSan8tInJKQDaALoZyM2e%20N0S3nx0-XQANL2kcY5MLKMSEkHyjtzkyEMzpKprJHhjXjwDwPyFphApIztklAPORW5ns4GyC9Wy-BCbyOqtpeWVuCIQYHiFig3AAInAwHAOgAKGpNerIRqpNoASgyAD5qrUUvwAHRQE5YJDQ6GyGTDZAILBQAngNHpTHQ7YkXGsslrZpUmkQcC4-qtWhc2lgXHzCBqFEUvCqFGlMoVKoEfoUg5HEwnD4df6A4FgiFwWHY-iywhAA) if that helps.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the result typed with name being a string in Field.
You need to type your string to the possible values, for exemple `type Name = 'myName' | 'isChecked'`

Also you have to type your reduce function or the type will be infered from the initial value.

Your expected result sould then be typed : `{[key in Name]: Field['value']}`.

I would make it Partial to avoid having to give values in the initial value.

Here is my proposition:

```
type Name = 'myName' | 'isChecked'

interface Input {
    type: 'text';
    name: Name;
    value: string;
}

interface Checkbox {
    type: 'checkbox';
    name: Name;
    value: boolean;
}

type Field = Input | Checkbox;

const fields: Field[] = [
    {
        name: 'myName',
        type: 'text',
        value: 'my name',
    },
    {
        name: 'isChecked',
        type: 'checkbox',
        value: false,
    }
];

type MyFormData = Partial<{[key in Name]: Field['value']}>

const getFormData = (fields: Field[]) => fields.reduce<MyFormData>((all, current) => ({
  ...all,
  [current.name]: current.value
}), {});


const { isChecked, myName } = getFormData(fields);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about this `{[key in Name]: Field['value']` trick, that helps for sure. The typed reduce function is useful too, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm using it this way:

```Typescript
export const getFormData = <Name extends Field["name"]>(fields: Field[]): { [key in Name]: Field["value"] } =>
  foldr((field, all) => (field.fields) ? { ...all, ...getFormData(field.fields) } : assoc(field.name, field.value, all),
    {},
    fields
  );

const { name, isChecked } = getFormData<'name' | 'isChecked'>(fields);
```

which is a much better but still can't get `name` or `isChecked` to be typed. 
Thanks for pointing me to right direction anyway, have a great day. Thank you!